# How do I resolve the "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-redux

After running "yarn run dev", I am met with the following error:

Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
Check the top-level render call using . See https://reactjs.org/link/warning-keys for more information.
at StarIcon
at Product (webpack-internal:///./src/components/Product.js:24:20)
at Div
at ProductFeed (webpack-internal:///./src/components/ProductFeed.js:13:24)
at main
at div
at Home (webpack-internal:///./src/pages/index.js:18:17)

Here is my Product.js file:

```
import React from 'react'
import Image from "next/image";
import { useState } from "react";
import { StarIcon } from "@heroicons/react/solid";
import * as CurrencyFormat from 'react-currency-format';
// import Currency from "react-currency-formatter";

const MAX_RATING = 5;
const MIN_RATING = 1;

function Product({id, title, price, description, category, image}) {
  const [rating] = useState(
    Math.floor(Math.random() * (MAX_RATING - MIN_RATING + 1)) + MIN_RATING
  );

  const [hasPrime] = useState(Math.random() < 0.5)

  return (
    <div className='relative flex flex-col m-5 bg-white z-30 p-10'>
      <p className='absolute top-2 right-2 text-xs italic text-gray-400'>{category}</p>

      <Image src={image} height={200} width={200} style="contain"></Image>

      <h4 className='my-3'>{title}</h4>

      <div className='flex'>
        {Array (rating)
        .fill()
        .map((_, i) => (
            <StarIcon className='h-5 text-yellow-500'></StarIcon>
        ))}
      </div>

      <p className='text-xs my-2 line-clamp-2'>{description}</p>

      <div className='mb-5'>
        <CurrencyFormat value={price} prefix={'$'}></CurrencyFormat>
      </div>

      {hasPrime && (
        <div className='flex items-center spaxe-x-2 -mt-5'>
          <img className='w-12' src='https://links.papareact.com/fdw' alt=""></img>
          <p className='text-xs text-gray-500'>FREE Next-Day Delivery</p>
        </div>
      )}

      <button className='mt-auto button'>Add to Basket</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Product
```

I have attempted to use several different types of key props throughout the files and none of the formats seem to resolve this issue. Surely I am going about this wrong. Any help here would be greatly appretiated!!

Answer (score 0):

This warning is addressed in [the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

> When you run this code, you’ll be given a warning that a key should be provided for list items. A “key” is a special string attribute you need to include when creating lists of elements.

...

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity.

Example code from the docs:

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const listItems = numbers.map((number) =>
  <li key={number.toString()}>
    {number}
  </li>
);
```

Comment: You can pass number type as `key`

Answer (score -1):

Try passing a unique key while iterating and rendering jsx i.e while iterating using .map
your code should look something like this

```
 <div className='flex'>
    {Array (rating)
    .fill()
    .map((_, i) => (
        <StarIcon className='h-5 text-yellow-500' key={i}> 
        </StarIcon>
    ))}
 </div>
```